# How to display a database query in a textview?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, textview

I have to make a Hangman app for a university project, at the moment I have created a SQLite database and put a couple of words in there. I am trying to run a query to select a random word and display it in a textview, but I am having trouble getting the result to display.

This is what I have so far

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

class Hangman extends Activity {

public TextView wordText;
public Button button02A;
private Button button01B;
private Button button03C;
private Button button04D;
private Button button05E;
private Button button06F;
private Button button07G;
private Button button1H;
private Button button09I;
private Button button10J;
private Button button11K;
private Button button12L;
private Button button13M;
private Button button14N;
private Button button15O;
private Button button16P;
private Button button18Q;
private Button button19R;
private Button button20S;
private Button button21T;
private Button button17U;
private Button button22V;
private Button button23W;
private Button button08X;
private Button button25Y;
private Button button26Z;
private Button button24Voice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hangman);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hangman, menu);
    return true;
}

public void assignButtons() {

    wordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordText);
    button02A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    button01B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button03C = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    button04D = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    button05E = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    button06F = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    button07G = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    button1H = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button09I = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09);
    button10J = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
    button11K = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
    button12L = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
    button13M = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
    button14N = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
    button15O = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
    button16P = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button16);
    button18Q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button18);
    button19R = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button19);
    button20S = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button20);
    button21T = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button21);
    button17U = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button17);
    button22V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button22);
    button23W = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button23);
    button08X = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    button25Y = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button25);
    button26Z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button26);
    button24Voice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button24);
}

}

class NewDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Create Database   
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="Puzzles";
public static final String COLUMN_PUZZLES = "Puzzlescol";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PUZZLES
          + " text not null);";


public NewDatabase(Context context, String name,
CursorFactory factory, int version) {
super(context, name, factory, version);
}
//Overriding onCreate and onUpgrade to create database
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(NewDatabase.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    }

public void insertRows(){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_ID, "1");
    values.put(COLUMN_PUZZLES, "MERMAID");
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, "2");
    values.put(COLUMN_PUZZLES, "SUITCASE");
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, "3");
    values.put(COLUMN_PUZZLES, "OSTRICH");

  }

public String randWord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.query("DATABASE_TABLE Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
    new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);

        return cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PUZZLES));
}

public void showWord(Cursor cur) {
    wordText.setText(cur);

}
}
```

Comment: you have just created NewDatabase class by extending SQLiteOpenHelper but not using in your application . first set a click listener to any button , create an instance of NewDatabase class for inserting or selecting value from database.you can also see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having?

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Create own Hungman application.
Create base DBHelper. Add some words to test. Set hangman logic.

Its better to create UI elements dynamically. Create layouts as box for new elements but put it there programmatically.

```
private LinearLayout lettersLayout;
private final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; ***
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hangman);
lettersLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lettersLay); **
for (String alphabetLetter : alphabet.split("(?!^)")) {
TextView alphabetLetterTxt = new TextView(this);
alphabetLetterTxt.setText(alphabetLetter);
lettersLayout.addView(alphabetLetter);
}
```

Here is simple example of work with SQLitte database:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DBHelper instance;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HangmanBase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
public static interface WORD extends BaseColumns {
        String TABLE_NAME = "wordTable";
        String WORD = "word";
        String DESCRIPTION = "wordDescription";
    }
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
    private static final String UNIQUE = "UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ABORT";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WORD = CREATE_TABLE + WORD.TABLE_NAME + " (" + WORD._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + WORD.WORD + " TEXT " + UNIQUE + ", " + WORD.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";
private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WORD);
    }
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE + WORD.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
public long addWord(String newWord, String newWordDescription) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(WORD.WORD.toUpperCase(Locale.UK), newWord);
        values.put(WORD.DESCRIPTION, newWordDescription);
        return getWritableDatabase().insert(WORD.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
public HangmanWord getRandomWord() {
        Cursor allWordsList = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + WORD.TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (allWordsList != null && allWordsList.getCount() > 0) {
            Random random = new Random();
            allWordsList.moveToPosition(random.nextInt(allWordsList.getCount()));
            return new HangmanWord(allWordsList.getString(allWordsList.getColumnIndex(WORD.WORD)),
                    allWordsList.getString(allWordsList.getColumnIndex(WORD.DESCRIPTION)));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```